# Select From Drop Down And Display On Same Page

Tags: php, jquery

I need something like a drop down box, you select for an example, New Members it will select newmembers.php but will display on the same page. Is this possible to do? Maybe it needs a id on the domain, like members.php?id=newmembers be easier if it don't.

This code is for txt but what form do I need and will it work with .php?

```
<?php
    $song = intval( $_GET[ 'song_id' ] );
    $songs = array( 0 => NULL, 1 => 'Song1', 2 => 'Song2', 3 => 'Song3' );
    echo file_get_contents( $songs[ $song ] . '.txt' );
?>
```

Hopefully someone will help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on Ajax calls. I'm not sure i understand you right, but I think you're just looking for an ajax call. This will select the member from you select dropdown and do an ajax call to newmembers.php and retrieve that member's information to use on the current page.

```
<select class='mySelect'>
    <option value=1>Member 1</option>
    <option value=2>Member 2</option>
</select>

$('.mySelect').select(function(){
    var memberid = $(this).val();
    $.post('newmembers.php', {id:memberid}, function(data){
        console.log(data); // this 'data' variable contains the information of this member (assuming newmembers.php grabbed their data from the database using their id);
        //use this 'data' object to populate the other fields on the page with this members information howwever you'd like. 
        }, json);
});
```

This is how a basic Ajax call works, and it looks like that's what you're looking for. You could use a php GET variable but that would require a page refresh, and ajax would work just as well.